# Checking if selected rows are favourite by user in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a `Venue` table with 20+ columns.
I also have a `favorite_venues` table with columns

```
id | userId | venueId
```

Here is my code to get venues

```
$this->Venue->virtualFields = array(
                    'bookedCount' => "SELECT count(*) FROM bookings WHERE venueId = Venue.id"
            );

            $result = $this->Venue->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions,                                    
                        'order' => array('Venue.bookedCount DESC'),
                        'limit' => 20,
                        'offset' => $offset * 20
            ));
```

i want to add a condition if i send userId, it should check every venue if its added to favourite list or not and set

```
$venue['isFavorite'] = yes/no
```

I dont want a for loop and check every venue i get. is there any way i can incorporate in same Mysql query in cakephp. I am not sure how to put yes/no as virtual field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `LEFT` join in your `favorite_venues` table, and then for example use a `CASE` statement in a virtual field that checks whether there is a linked row.

Here's an untested example to illustrate what I mean. I don't know how the user ID is involved, so you got to figure that on your own.

```
$this->Venue->virtualFields = array(
    'bookedCount' => "SELECT count(*) FROM bookings WHERE venueId = Venue.id",
    'isFavorite' => 'CASE WHEN FavoriteVenues.id IS NOT NULL THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END'
);

$result = $this->Venue->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,                                    
    'order' => array('Venue.bookedCount DESC'),
    'limit' => 20,
    'offset' => $offset * 20,
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'favorite_venues',
            'alias' => 'FavoriteVenues',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'FavoriteVenues.venueId = Venue.id',
            )
        )
    ),
    // don't forget to group to prevent duplicate results
    'group' => 'Venue.id'
));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Virtual Fields > Virtual fields set in controller with JOINS](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#pagination-and-virtual-fields-set-in-controller-with-joins)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > Joining Tables](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**
- **[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual / SQL Statement Syntax / ...  / CASE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)**